# Is there a javascript / angularjs function to save form data in cache when redirecting?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, caching

I'd like the data to be cached when I redirect, so when I click a button that returns me to the forms, the data will still be there.

In my scenario, I have a form with a couple inputs and a dropdown with an "add" button beside it. If I click the "add" button, it redirects me to another page (the redirect is necessary) if I want to add data to the dropdown. Then I can click a button (a back button) that returns me to the original form, with my previously typed information in the forms and the updated dropdown.

Comment: I would recommend to save your data in the browser local storage before redirecting, and then retrieve it from there once you are in the new page. You can do this with regular javascript or if you are using angularjs, there are some libraries out there that make this easier. https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) works for caching values in the browser